# WEKA EEG data Filter creation

Tags: weka

I am currently working on a project involving EEG data analysis, specifically focusing on identifying patterns and correlations within different brain regions.

To achieve this, I am interested in utilizing the Partition Membership filter in Weka. However, I am uncertain about how to configure this filter to effectively analyze EEG data where each partition corresponds to specific channels within a distinct brain region, for example, Partition 1 = Channels Fp1, F3, F7; Partition 2 = Channels Fp2, F4, F8, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.